# How i can do SVN Repositories Backup step by step

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, svn, command-line-interface

How i can do SVN Repositories Backup step by step.... i want to backup the Repositories itself .... i don't want to backup it as folder ....

Comment: Why not as a dump file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to do Subversion backups?](http://serverfault.com/questions/52252/best-way-to-do-subversion-backups)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**step 1**
Create a script or batch file that runs the command

```
svnadmin dump REPOS_PATH > backupfile
```

svnadmin is a program that comes with svn it will be in the bin folder

backupfile is the file that the repository will get dumped to

REPOS_PATH is the location of the repository

see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html for more details

**step 2.**
Run the script/batch file to test the backup.

**step 3.**
Test that the backup works by running the command

```
svnadmin load test_path < backupfile
```

Now try out the repository created in test_path to make sure it works ok - it should and as a bonus it should work with newer versions of svn.

Comment: please if you know another method becouse it is hard to understand ....and becouse i dont have a wide background about this OS

Comment: edited so it cannot be easier to understand HTH

Comment: please if you can help me .... when i made the backup in the "root" /home ... the size of the root space not enough so i try to make the backup on other place "/backup" but the following message appear : (-bash: file_name : Prmission denied)

Comment: Few questions - commands to find answers in brackets.

What operating system (uname -a)? what user is this running as (whoami)? does the /backup folder exist and do you have permissions (ls -l /)? Is this on a disk that is mounted read/write (mount)?

Comment: -1 for not mentioning the files that `svnadmin dump` does not include (hooks and such). Use `svnadmin hotcopy` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Following a script that you can save as : svnbackup.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash

appname=`basename $0`

#
# Set some defaults
#
increment=100
start=""
default_history_file="last_saved"
history_file=""
dumpfilepath="."
dumpfilename="dumpfile"
verbose=false
sshopts=""
identity=""

#
# Function to explain how to use the program
#
function usage () {
    echo
    echo "$appname [-h]"
    echo "$appname [-v] [-i increment] [-s start_rev] [--scp remote] [--identity ssh-key] [--ssh-opts ssh options] [--history-file file] [--out-dir directory name] [--compress (gzip|bzip2)] [--file-name dumpfile-base-name] svn_repository_path"
    cat - <<EOF

This script dumps a subversion repository to a series of compressed
files.  It uses a local file to remember the last changeset dumped so
the script can be used to generate files for backups.

Using the --scp option, the backup files can be generated on one
machine and copied to a backup server once dumped.

  -v             -- Verbose mode
  -i increment   -- How many revisions to include in each dump file.
  --file-name base -- Base name for dump files, defaults to "dumpfile".
  -s start_rev   -- First revision to dump.
  --scp remote   -- Location for remote backups.  Files are transfered via scp,
                    then removed from the local directory.
  --identity     -- Identity file for scp transfer
  --ssh-opts      -- options to use for scp
  --history-file -- path and filename of historyfile to use
  --out-dir      -- path where svn dump files should be written, defaults to "."
  --compress     -- compression method (gzip or bzip2, defaults to bzip2)
EOF
    echo
    echo "Example:"
    echo "  $appname -v -i 100 --scp user@backupserver:/backups/svn /svn/Project"
    echo
    exit $1
}

compress_app="bzip2"
compress_ext="bzip2"

#
# Process arguments
#
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    opt="$1"
    case "$opt" in
        -h) usage 0;;
        -i) increment=$2;
            shift;;
        -s) start=$2;
            shift;;
        --scp) dest="$2"; 
            shift;;
        --identity) identity="$2";
            shift;;
        --ssh-opts)  sshopts="$2";
            shift;;
        --history-file) history_file="$2";
            shift;;
        --out-dir) dumpfilepath="$2";
            shift;;
        --file-name) dumpfilename="$2";
            shift;;
        -v) verbose=true;;
        --compress)
            case "$2" in
                bzip2|bz|bzip) 
                    compress_app="bzip2"; 
                    compress_ext="bzip2";;
                gzip|gz)
                    compress_app="gzip";
                    compress_ext="gz";;
            esac;
            shift;;
        *) break;;
    esac
    shift
done

repository="$1"
if [ -z "$repository" ]
then
    echo "Failed: Repository argument required"
    usage 1
fi

if [ -z "$history_file" ]
then
    history_file="$dumpfilepath/$default_history_file"
fi

if [ "x${start}" = "x" ]
then
    # if [ -s $history_file ]              #Blocco Rinominato per NON Tenere Conto Last_saved
    # then
        # loop_first=`cat $history_file`
    # else
        # loop_first=0
    # fi
     loop_first=0
else
    loop_first=$start
fi
youngest=`svnlook youngest "$repository"`

$verbose && echo "Backing up: $repository"
$verbose && echo "      From: $loop_first"
$verbose && echo "        To: $youngest"
if [ "$dest" != "" ]
then
    $verbose && echo "      Dest: $dest"
fi
if [ "$identity" != "" ] ; then
    $verbose && echo "  Identity: $identity"
fi
if [ "$sshopts" != "" ] ; then
    $verbose && echo "  ssh opts: $sshopts"
fi
$verbose && echo "Hist. file: $history_file"
$verbose && echo "Chunk size: $increment"

#
# Function to do the backup for one set of revisions
#
function backup_revs () {
    typeset first=$1
    typeset last=$2
    typeset repo=$3

    if [ "$first" != "0" ]
    then
        incremental="--incremental"
    fi

    repo_name=`basename "$repo"`
    dumpfile="$dumpfilepath/${dumpfilename}-${repo_name}-${first}-${last}.${compress_ext}"

    $verbose && echo -n "Dumping ${first}:${last} ..."

    svnadmin dump -q "$repo" $incremental --revision ${first}:${last} \
        | "$compress_app" > "$dumpfile"
    RC=$?

    $verbose && echo

    if [ $RC -ne 0 ]
    then
        rm -f "$dumpfile"
        return $RC
    fi

    $verbose && echo "Created $dumpfile"

    if [ "$dest" != "" ]
    then
        if [ -z "$identity" ] ; then
            scp $sshopts "$dumpfile" "$dest"
        else
            scp $sshopts -i $identity "$dumpfile" "$dest"
        fi
        RC=$?
        rm -f "$dumpfile"
    fi

    return $RC
}

#
# Do the incremental dumps
#

if [[ $youngest -eq $loop_first ]]
then
    $verbose && echo "No new changesets to dump"
    exit 0
fi

let loop_last=($loop_first + $increment)

if [[ $loop_first -ne 0 ]]
then
    let loop_first=($loop_first + 1)
fi

while [[ $loop_first -le $youngest ]]
do

    if [ $loop_last -lt $youngest ]
    then
        # A full "increment"
        backup_revs $loop_first $loop_last "$repository" || exit 1
        #echo $loop_last > $history_file
    else
        # In case the last few revs do not make up a full "increment"
        backup_revs $loop_first $youngest "$repository" || exit 1
        #echo $youngest > $history_file
    fi

    let loop_first=($loop_last + 1)
    let loop_last=($loop_last + $increment)
done

exit 0
```

Comment: The storage of the last revision backed up in the history file does not occur with the above script because the lines associated with writing and reading of the history file have been commented out. Uncommenting them allows them to work properly (be sure to comment out the currently uncommented line 'loop_first=0' as that replaced the work of the commented out block.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop the server running
2. Copy the entire directory containing the repo and hooks and config files.
3. Copy your Apache config too, if you use it and it's not stored in above dir anyway.

that's it.

You can restore on the same machine, or a similar one (eg windows -> windows). if you want to restore from Windows to Linux (say) then you'll want to dump and load the repository instead. You'll still need to copy the rest of the directory as well.

Suggestions to use rsync to copy everything is a good one (but you;ll have to stop the server to always get a good backup), or use svnsync which is an excellent incremental backup utility for SVN. (you'll still have to copy the hooks and config as well though - I rsync those and svnsync the repo)

Comment: Good point - stopping the server helps if the repo is in use. Saving the ssh configs would be a point too.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a copy of the svn directory.

Edit:

As already mentioned - you need to stop the svn server first.

You need to stop apache and ssh too, if you use them to access your repo.

Comment: may be you mean the following command :- svnadmin hotcopy path/to/repository path/to/backup --clean-logs ..... if you mean it i read in some referance this method it is not recommended

Comment: No - just copy the folder. Your repo reside in a folder. You can just copy or better rsync the folder.

Comment: Just copying the directory without stopping all SVN access first is a really bad idea, you might end up with an inconsistent backup. Always use svnadmin hotcopy or completely stop all SVN access as noted in the answer by @gbjbaanb

Comment: That's true - if edited my post to reflect these issues.