# Walkthrough on creating a script to backup subversion on Linux

Tags: linux, backup, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to do Subversion backups?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52252/best-way-to-do-subversion-backups)

I'm not a Linux admin so a full walkthrough is needed.  I'm running Gentoo 1.16 I believe.

I know the elements I need as I can do it "manually".

-run svnadmin hotcopy /shared/svnrepos /svnbackup
-tar the /svnbackup folder

That's really it.  I just need a script of some kind and be told explicitly how to add it to cron in Gentoo to make it run nightly.

I will then use pscp from a Windows backup server to grab the archive and copy it to the backup server.

I'm happy to answer any questions, file locations, etc. I'm just still learning this stuff.

Comment: I know how to do it, that was the original link I read.  I just didn't know how to schedule/automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to crontab by
$crontab -e
this string (2 0 is time)

2 0 * * * /path/to/my/script.sh

create script.sh, open, and wite into it all you shell commands one at line with full paths.

Instead run pscp from windows, you can start copiyng from gentoo.

For that start ssh server on windows ( a lot of on sf.net) + key auth.

and put in script.sh

scp /.././././my.tar user@my-windows-host:path/...

Comment: good deal.  I will test this weekend.  The reason I was going to run pscp from windows is because I have a batch file that creates 7 days worth in "Mon" etc. folders.  I suppose I could do the same here and simply create 7 script.sh scripts.  Just have to read on what the cron "timing" is.